# Tstamp Interval to always start at midnight

Tags: mysql, timestamp, intervals

I have this query that shows me the interval for 1 hour. The issue i have is when it's set to 1 hour it shows the perfect data it starts from 12AM up to 11PM

```
SELECT 

FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t_stamp) - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t_stamp), 3600)) as Tstamp,
Col1,
Col2

FROM table


WHERE DATE(t_stamp) BETWEEN '2018-10-15' AND '2018-10-15'


GROUP BY Tstamp

ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
```

The output of this looks something like this

```
Tstamp                  Col1    Col2
2018-10-15 00:00:00     73.43   72.12
2018-10-15 01:00:00     73.29   71.96
2018-10-15 02:00:00     73.43   72.21
.
.
.
.
.
2018-10-15 16:00:00     74.24   72.85
2018-10-15 17:00:00     74.37   72.85
2018-10-15 18:00:00     74.20   72.64
2018-10-15 19:00:00     74.01   72.42
2018-10-15 20:00:00     73.80   72.42
2018-10-15 21:00:00     73.73   72.34
2018-10-15 22:00:00     73.59   72.13
2018-10-15 23:00:00     73.51   72.12
```

But when I set the interval to 3 hours or 8 hours it doesn't start at midnight, if for example the selected date is 2018-10-15 and the interval is set to 3 hours, it starts at 2018-10-14 11:00 PM instead of 2018-10-15 12:00 AM

```
SELECT 

FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t_stamp) - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t_stamp), 10800)) as Tstamp,
Col1,
Col2

FROM table


WHERE DATE(t_stamp) BETWEEN '2018-10-15' AND '2018-10-15'


GROUP BY Tstamp

ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
```

This is the output when the interval is 3 hours

```
Tstamp                  Col1    Col2
2018-10-14 23:00:00     73.43   72.12
2018-10-15 02:00:00     73.43   72.21
2018-10-15 05:00:00     73.73   72.42
2018-10-15 08:00:00     73.29   71.96
2018-10-15 11:00:00     73.36   72.34
2018-10-15 14:00:00     73.98   72.64
2018-10-15 17:00:00     74.37   72.85
2018-10-15 20:00:00     73.80   72.42
2018-10-15 23:00:00     73.51   72.12
```

I was hoping for an output like this when the interval is at 3 hours and 8 hours, where if the selected date is 2018-10-15, it will start the time at 12 midnight and not the day before.

```
Tstamp                  Col1    Col2
2018-10-15 00:00:00     73.43   72.21
2018-10-15 03:00:00     73.72   72.99
2018-10-15 06:00:00     73.34   72.12
2018-10-15 09:00:00     73.43   72.77
2018-10-15 12:00:00     73.29   72.42
2018-10-15 15:00:00     74.15   72.76
2018-10-15 18:00:00     74.20   72.64
2018-10-15 21:00:00     73.73   72.34
.
.
.
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Structure and Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `Col1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Col2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_stamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `tablet_stampndx` (`t_stamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table`
(`Col1`,
`Col2`,
`t_stamp`)
VALUES
('73.43','72.12','2018-10-15 00:00:00'),
('73.29','71.96','2018-10-15 01:00:00'),
('73.43','72.21','2018-10-15 02:00:00'),
('73.72','72.99','2018-10-15 03:00:00'),
('73.80','72.55','2018-10-15 04:00:00'),
('73.73','72.42','2018-10-15 05:00:00'),
('73.34','72.12','2018-10-15 06:00:00'),
('73.94','73.20','2018-10-15 07:00:00'),
('73.29','71.96','2018-10-15 08:00:00'),
('73.43','72.77','2018-10-15 09:00:00'),
('73.43','72.12','2018-10-15 10:00:00'),
('73.36','72.34','2018-10-15 11:00:00'),
('73.29','72.42','2018-10-15 12:00:00'),
('73.51','72.34','2018-10-15 13:00:00'),
('73.98','72.64','2018-10-15 14:00:00'),
('74.15','72.76','2018-10-15 15:00:00'),
('74.24','72.85','2018-10-15 16:00:00'),
('74.37','72.85','2018-10-15 17:00:00'),
('74.20','72.64','2018-10-15 18:00:00'),
('74.01','72.42','2018-10-15 19:00:00'),
('73.80','72.42','2018-10-15 20:00:00'),
('73.73','72.34','2018-10-15 21:00:00'),
('73.59','72.13','2018-10-15 22:00:00'),
('73.51','72.12','2018-10-15 23:00:00')
```

So far I've tried using DATE_SUB function but it hasn't really given me the output that I wanted. I have `10-15` selected on the date interval but its showing me data from `10-14` which is really not what i wanted to see

```
SELECT 

t_stamp,
Col1,
Col2


FROM table

WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2018-10-15 00:00:00', INTERVAL 3 HOUR) 
    AND DATE_ADD('2018-10-15 23:59:59', INTERVAL 3 HOUR)

GROUP BY t_stamp
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC


2018-10-14 21:02:17 73.50   72.21
2018-10-14 21:07:17 73.51   72.21
2018-10-14 21:12:17 73.50   72.21
2018-10-14 21:17:17 73.50   72.19
2018-10-14 21:22:17 73.50   72.21
2018-10-14 21:27:17 73.50   72.21
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sorry I added some sample output of the query I hope this made it a bit better

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment

Comment: @Strawberry - You are on a mission to civilise! I absolutely love this about you. Cheers!

Comment: @montypython in hope more than expectation

Comment: @Strawberry idk if this is better or not

Comment: The data set in the ddls and the data set in the question are different. Help us to help you.

Comment: @Strawberry ah shoot sorry i updated it again

Comment: *＋1* for keeping things on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SEC_TO_TIME((FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(t_stamp)/10800)*10800))x FROM `table`;
```

Comment: oh wait yes i think it is, I added "as x" on the end, im gonna try with an 8 hour interval

Comment: I changed it to 
`DISTINCT SEC_TO_TIME((FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(t_stamp)))/10800)*10800)) as x` and I can see the hour is what I wanted but the date is not showing? and when I try to include the other 2 columns it changed back to 00:00:00

Comment: So don't do that then :-(

Comment: But i need them there :'(